# Problems with Tkinter Binding to enter/return

Tags: python, class, tkinter, python-2.5

My program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master,width = 100,height = 100)
        frame.bind('<Return>',self.ret)
        frame.pack()

    def ret(self):
        print "You pressed enter"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It opens up the window but when I press return or enter it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have to set the focus on the frame to respond to the event:

```
frame = Frame(master,width = 100,height = 100)
frame.focus_set()
```

By the way, callbacks receive a Tkinter event as an argument, so `ret` should be defined as `def ret(self, event)`, or bind the event with a lambda function and don't use the argument:

```
frame.bind('<Return>', lambda e: self.ret())
```